# Can a single Android activity have 2 layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

Can a single Android activity file contain two XML layout files? If it can, does the second one need to be in the Android manifest, too?

For example, if I create an Android activity, it comes with a layout file. If I create another layout file and wish to link it with the first one, is that possible?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attackpage);
    setContentView(R.layout.addplayer);
}
```

If I add another **`setContentView`** into **`onCreate`**, is that correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623150/set-two-layouts-for-one-activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301440/loading-multiple-layouts-dynamically-within-one-activity-on-android

Comment: No, you should not do that. why you want to do this? There must be a better of fixing your problem.

Comment: I'm new in android. I dont have any better solution.

Comment: Do you want see both layouts at same time?

Answer (score 1):

No, what you are doing here is not working. This will only load the last layout. A solution might be to add the second layout programmatically by using a `LayoutInflater`. An ugly solution would be to combine both and switch the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

That does not work at all. An activity can only one layout.xml file at a time. You can achieve what you are trying to do is by combining both attackpage.xml and addplayer.xml into one single layout.xml file according to your design and then call single setContentView() method on

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout.xml);}
```

Or optionally you can have two frameLayouts or Fragment views in your single layout.xml and dynamically manipulate every single frame layout or fragment seperately. There are so many design options but what you are trying to do does not work for 100 %.